# JavaScript - focus input and set cursor position by cords

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, focus

I have a code line that select an element (usually input element) by cords.
But I need to set the cursor position as well (if the cords are pointed to the middle of the text - place the cursor there)

I have a cords object:

```
{x: 100, y: 100}
```

And this line that focus on the input element in those cords

```
document.elementFromPoint(cords.x - window.pageXOffset, cords.y - window.pageYOffset).focus();
```

Pure JavaScript is needed

Comment: Edited. I already have the cords, I recorded where the user clicked. I want to simulate later his actions, so I need to place the cursor where he did

Comment: It's going to be complicated to calculate where the text is in the element, taking margins, borders, and what not into consideration, not to mention to the actual text size etc. and then figuring out where to place the caret. This sounds like an X/Y problem, why would you need this?

Comment: I need to record user actions and simulate them later. I can save more information on user`s click event (I have a click listener) if that would help

Comment: You'd have to get the element from the point, then find the top left corner of that element and figure out how far it is from the documents top left corner, and what you have left is the position in the element. Then you have to figure out where the text is in the element, the text size and length etc, and then how many characters in the caret is positioned, and then use `setSelectionRange` or `createTextRange` to set the caret. It's going to be somewhat complicated.

Comment: Looks very complicated, based on the font, font-size, space between lines, space between chars... Sounds like impossible to do it perfect that way.
Maybe there is a listener for cursor position change? for the whole document (not a specific object)?